# How put string in url routing rules in yii2?

Tags: php, routes, yii2, yii-url-manager

In yii2 I have controller:

```
public function actionRequest($date) {
...
}
```

I need url `request/2015-12-03` instead of `request?date=2015-12-03`

So, how to get date from routing if it is string or date? This does not work (page not found):
`'user/request/<date:\w+>' => 'user/request'`

The strange thing is that `view`, `update` and `delete` actions work good. Url `request?date=2015-12-03` also works. I use Apache server.
main.php:

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => '',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'user/view/<id:\d+>' => 'user/view', // works
                'user/update/<id:\d+>' => 'user/update', // works
                'user/delete/<id:\d+>' => 'user/delete', // works
                'user/request/<date:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}>' => 'user/request', // doesn't work
                'user/request/<date:\w+>' => 'user/request', // doesn't work
                [
                    'pattern' => 'login',
                    'route' => 'user/login',
                ],
                [
                    'pattern' => 'logout',
                    'route' => 'user/logout',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        ...
]
```

.htaccess is from this article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/
.htaccess in root:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

.htaccess in /frontend/web:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: show your confg/main.php  component  urlManager  configuration

Comment: rules work, because other rules for other controllers work. I have `'baseUrl' => '', 'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'showScriptName' => false, 'rules' => [...]`

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression for date must be like this

```
<date:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}>
```

Comment: Very good idea, but I don't know why it does not work.. any ideas? in fact, is it possible to use string for regex?

Comment: trun on the pretty URL also

Comment: Sorry, it was the easiest thing I could imagine. Is this URL works `request?date=2015-12-03`? Which web server do you use - apache or nginx? What Is your .htaccess or nginx.conf respectively?

Comment: Action `actionRequest()` declared in `UserController`?

Comment: Sure, it is declared there